# RunmtimeTypeHandle to type

Tags: c++-cli

Here is a sample program that wraps up a managed enum for unmanaged use. I want to be able to get wrapped enums back from unmanaged code and convert them back to managed enums with as little overhead as possible. My current scheme requires creating a GCHandle to the Type object. I was thinking maybe there is a way to use the RuntimeTypeHandle value instead to remove this overhead. Is that possible? Or any other efficiency suggestions anyone has.

```
public value class Stuff {
public:
    enum class Modes { A, B };
};

struct enum_wrap {
    intptr_t type;
    int value;
};

void g(enum_wrap e);
enum_wrap h();

void f(Stuff::Modes mode)
{
    enum_wrap wrap;
    wrap.value = (int)mode;
    wrap.type = static_cast<intptr_t>(GCHandle::ToIntPtr(GCHandle::Alloc(Stuff::Modes::typeid)));

    g(wrap);

    // ...

    enum_wrap ret = h();

    Type^ ret_type = safe_cast<Type^>(GCHandle::FromIntPtr(static_cast<IntPtr>(ret.type)).Target);
    Enum^ e_obj = (Enum^)Enum::ToObject(ret_type, ret.value);
    Console::Write(e_obj->GetType());
    Console::Write(": ");
    Console::WriteLine(e_obj);
}

#pragma unmanaged

enum_wrap g_enum;

void g(enum_wrap e) {
    g_enum = e;
}

enum_wrap h() {
    return g_enum;
}
```

I know this leaks because of never freeing GCHandles. I already have code that can deal with that if this is the best approach I can find. But I'm hoping to not need the Type objects at all.

Edit 1: Put Modes enum in a class so it works right.

Comment: I don't understand the question. A `Type` object is a singleton, you'll get one `RuntimeType` instance per type per appdomain. So there's no allocation here, but when you write `Modes^ e` instead of `Modes e` you create a *boxed* enum value, so you allocate an object for no reason there. Just write `Modes e = safe_cast<Modes>(int_val);` and be done with it.

Comment: Ok . I fleshed out a much larger example so you can see why I want to do this.

Comment: Sorry to bug you Lucas but any ideas?

Comment: Oh, I didn't have time to look at your question -  I'll try a couple ideas when I'll have an IDE handy, but I'm quite sure there's a clean solution to this. Right now I'd say try with `gcroot<Enum^>` to keep a reference to a boxed enum, it keeps its type information along in the box, but this solution requires 2 ref objects for each value, so it's suboptimal.

Comment: If I could turn a Type.TypeHandle.Value back into a Type object that would save having to make a GCHandle. Also enum_wrap needs to be unmanaged, hence the intptr to a GChandle instead of a gcroot.

Comment: A `gcroot` is just an unmanaged wrapper class over a `GCHandle`, and it prevents handle leaks

Comment: I use a `gchandle` class I made that does the same thing but also has move semantics. Since there is overhead to a GCHandle I was hoping I could avoid it completely by using Type.TypeHandle.Value